# Can the Azure App Service Inbound IP ever change?

Tags: azure, ip, domain, service, azure-app-services

We are using "custom domains" in a azure app service. A DNS is pointing to the IP address of the app service listed in -> custom domains -> IP Address. Everything works as expected (y)

Here's the question:
Can this IP ever change? Should I be careful with any kind of configuration eg upscaling? Or is this IP reliable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the IP can change (perhaps a CNAME record would be better?).

Generally it will only change due to a platform health issue and not something you can inadvertently do within the portal.  Not even a scale up will cause it.